# y-axis ticks of seaborn displot

Tags: histogram, seaborn, distribution

Can I know what are the ticks at y axis mean?

I created a seaborn.distplot of `Age` column from titanic dataset from kaggle. I know distplot is similar to histograms and values are between bins. But I was not able to understand what the y-axis ticks meant. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Univariate_distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph shows the probability density. You may read it as follows; choosing e.g. the bar from 20 to 24 years. This shows a probability density of 0.035. The probability to have someone between 20 and 24 years is hence (24-20)*0.035 = 0.14 = 14%.

Apart you can learn a lot of qualitative things, e.g. it is interesting that there are more than twice as many children aged below 4 years than between 4 and 8 years.